# Android: can't compare time in timeMillis

Tags: android, datetime, compare

i want to compare two time (hour and minute) in textView. I try to convert there into millisecond, but it looks does'n work. Or maybe you have other way to covert  . .

```
String startTime = (String) tvDisplayTime.getText(); 
String endTime = (String) tvDisplayTime.getText();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");   

    try {
        Date StartDate = sdf.parse(startTime);
        long timeInMillisecondsStart = StartDate.getTime();

        Date EndDate = sdf.parse(endTime);
        long timeInMillisecondsEnd = Enddate.getTime();

        long result = timeInMillisecondsEnd-timeInMillisecondsStart;

            if (result > 0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Work ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                          

            }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Failed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mate check your code :

```
String startTime = (String) tvDisplayTime.getText(); 
String endTime = (String) tvDisplayTime.getText();
```

your getting the same text all the time ...

endTime and startTime are always equal.

Comment: i try to use `after`, but not working. Result always failed. `if (EndDate.after(StartDate)){ work } else{failed}`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert to a time in milliseconds. Just use the [compareTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) method on your date objects.

From the docs...

Returns:
an int < 0 if this Date is less than the specified Date, 0 if they are equal, and an int > 0 if this Date is greater.

Answer (score 0):

Your method works if you enter the time in the specified format /e.g. HH:mm/, but this can be quite frustrating for the user. Why not use TimePicker instead. There in the onTimeSet callback you get the time set by the user in int variables

> public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)

Example here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html